# Is there any use for std::nullptr_t except to disambiguate nullptr parameters?

Tags: c++

Is there really any use for the `std::nullptr_t` type except to help avoid function calls with a `nullptr`?

```
void f(int* pi) {}

void f(std::nullptr_t np) {}
```

Without `f(std::nullptr_t)`, `f(nullptr)` would call `f(int*)`.

Thanks

Comment: The answer is No. But that answer is too short to fit, so it has to be a comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's its only use case .

Comment: Why should I prefer that over `if (pi == nullptr) return;` ?